# SwiftUI LazyVStack child disappears when scrolling

Tags: swiftui, lazyvstack

I have a simple LazyVStack with a custom view. I noticed that when it is scrolled under the navigation bar the view disappears prematurely. Is there a good work around of this besides to disable scrolling when it is not needed? I have attached an animated gif of the issue.

```
  NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(model.wallets, id: \.id) { wallet in
                        GalleryCell(wallet: wallet)
                    }
                }
            }
```

[image]

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? Thank you